# .net core 2.2 cors policy per endpoint setup

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm trying to setup cors policy for my api in a .net core 2.2 project.

```
 services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("policy1", builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .WithOrigins(backendConfig.BACKOFFICE_ORIGIN)
                    .WithMethods("GET", "POST")
                    .WithHeaders("Content-Type");
            });

            options.AddPolicy("policy2", builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .WithOrigins(backendConfig.BACKOFFICE_ORIGIN)
                    .WithMethods("PUT")
                    .WithHeaders("Content-Type");
            });
        });
```

Then in Configure I do the following :

```
app.UseCors("policy1");
app.UseCors("policy2");
```

And I added

```
[EnableCors("policy1")]
```

And

```
[EnableCors("policy2")]
```

To two differents endpoint.

But when calling the second endpoint using ajax, I receive always

Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44377/campaigns/default_campaign' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.

Event If the attribute 
 [EnableCors("policy2")] is setted on it.

The two endpoint are totally different.

Any idea plz?